# how to insert a combobox in c# linq from another table

Tags: linq, combobox, datetimepicker

I tried this but it jumps to the error message 
I think there is some thing wrong in the date and combo box entry from another table!!!!!!!!!!!!(The city here is Foreign Key data type is int) 
Someone could help !!!

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
Employee employee =new Employee();
employee.FName=txtFName;
employee.LName=txtLName;
employee.DOB=DTPicker.value;
employee.city=ComboCity.selectedItem.ToString();
MyDB.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(employee);
MyDB.SubmitChanges();
txtFName.text="";
txtLastName.text="";
DTPicker.Value="";
ComboCity.text="";
MessageBox.Show("Record Entered")
}
catch
{
MessageBox.Show("Wrong Entry");
}
}
```

And Thanks

Comment: Change this: `employee.DOB=DTPicker.value;` to `employee.DOB=Convert.ToDatetime(DTPicker.value);`

Comment: could I enter fixed values in linq as will because I have a field I want to enter it in the code without any user entry